# How to animate multiple effects at same time using jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, effects

I am using jQuery's `animate()` function to animate a `div`. When I give multiple effects like height 140 and width 200, then the next effects start only after the previous effects finish. I want to execute simultaneously. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gal_item").hover(function(){                    
        $(this).children().animate({height:110},"medium");
        $(this).children().animate({width:110},"medium");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gal_item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="120" height="100" /></div>
<div class="gal_item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="120" height="100" /></div>
```

Comment: please post your code. You should be able to do this:
$('#id').animate({width:200px,height:140px},slow)

Comment: I added code!. Plz check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The animate method accepts multiple style declarations, you can simply...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gal_item").hover(function(){                    
        $(this).children().animate({
            height:110,
            width: 110
        }, "medium");
    });
});
```